# Error of "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

This is my blade view where i am taking values of total closing report and total deposit. if it differs, automatically difference is being calculated and displayed. On the basis of difference, below details need to be added for the difference amount and stored in cashoutexpense.
For example - Total Closing Report is 200 , Total Deposit is 100 then details need to be provided for difference amount. i.e 100. In this case, suppose user has given input for expense amount as 50 in one textbox and 50 in another by adding another row.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label>Total Closing Report</label>
        <input class="form-control" v-model="form.closing_report_total" @change="calculate" type="number" required name="closing_report_total" placeholder="Enter Closing Report Total">   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label>Total Deposit</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="form.total_deposit" @change="calculate" required name="total_deposit" placeholder="Enter Total Deposit">   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label>Difference</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="form.difference" name="difference"  placeholder="Enter Difference" readonly>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row" v-if="form.difference != 0" v-for="(comment, k) in form.cashoutexpenses" :key="k">
    <div class="col-4">
         <input type="text" class="flatpickr form-control" v-model="comment.expense_date" required name="expense_date" placeholder="Click here to choose Date"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
         <input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="comment.amount" required name="amount" placeholder="Enter Expense Amount" @change="calculate_error">   
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="comment.comment" required name="comment" placeholder="Enter Expense Comments">  
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
         <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" @click="removeRow(k)">Remove</button>  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row" v-if="form.left > 0">
     <div class="col-12">
          <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="button" value="Add Row" @click="addRow()"> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Below is my script code for the same.

```
<script>

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted: function() {
    },
    computed: {
        difference: function() {
            return this.form.difference = this.form.closing_report_total - this.form.total_deposit;
        }
    },
    data: {
        form: {
            closing_report_total : 0.00,
            total_deposit: 0.00,
            difference: 0.00,
            left: 0.00,
            comments: '',
            cashoutexpenses: [],
            buffer: []
        }, 
        
    },
    methods: {
        addRow() {
            this.form.cashoutexpenses.push({
                date: '',
                amount: '',
                comment: '',
            });
            this.form.buffer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form.cashoutexpenses));
        },
        removeRow(index) {
            this.form.cashoutexpenses.splice(index, 1);
            this.form.buffer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form.cashoutexpenses));
        },
        calculate: function() {
            this.form.difference = this.form.closing_report_total - this.form.total_deposit;
            this.form.cashoutexpenses = [];
            this.form.buffer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form.cashoutexpenses));
            if(this.form.difference != 0) {
                this.addRow();
            }
        },
        calculate_error: function() {
            this.form.left = this.form.difference - this.form.cashoutexpenses.reduce((a,b)=> (a + (parseInt(b['amount'])||0)),0);
            if(this.form.left<0) {
                alert("Sum of expenses should not exceed total amount");
                for(var i=0; i<this.form.cashoutexpenses.length;i++) {
                    if(this.form.cashoutexpenses[i].amount!=this.form.buffer[i].amount) {
                        this.form.buffer[i].amount = 0;
                        this.form.cashoutexpenses[i].amount=this.form.difference - this.form.buffer.reduce((a,b)=> (a + (parseInt(b['amount'])||0)),0);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(this.form.left>0) {
                alert("Please add "+this.form.left+" more");
            }
            this.form.buffer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form.cashoutexpenses));
        },
        formSubmit: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let currentObj = this;
           // let data = new FormData();
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('closing_report_total', this.form.closing_report_total);
            formData.append('total_deposit', this.form.total_deposit);
            formData.append('difference', this.form.difference);
            formData.append('form.cashoutexpenses', this.form.cashoutexpenses);
            let config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
            axios.post('/cashoutdetails/store', formData ,config)
            .then(response => {
                //console.log(formData);
                //alert('data saved');
                //window.location.href = "{{ route('cashoutdetails.index')}}";
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert('Error');
            }); 
        }
    }
})

</script>
```

if i check for the same in vue plugin of mozilla firefox, correct data is being displayed which is as follows --

```
cashoutexpenses:Array[2]
   0:Object
     amount:"50"
     comment:"test2"
     date:""
     expense_date:"2021-10-10"
   1:Object
     amount:"50"
     comment:"test3"
     date:""
     expense_date:"2021-10-12"
```

Now in my controller , i am fetching the data which is as below -

```
        $comments = $request->form_cashoutexpenses;
        //return $comments;
        foreach($comments as $c) {
            return $c;
            $cashout_comments = new CashOutExpenses;
            $cashout_comments->cashout_id = $cashout_details->id;
            $cashout_comments->expense_date = $c['expense_date'];
            $cashout_comments->amount = $c['amount'];
            $cashout_comments->explanation = $c['comment'];
            $cashout_comments->save();
        } 

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Details added!',
        ], 201);
```

If i return $comments, it gives reply as [object Object],[object Object] otherwise it returns error for foreach.

if i return $request->all(); ... it gives following output -

{"closing_report_total":"200","total_deposit":"100","difference":"100","form.cashoutexpenses":"[object Object]"}

Please help me to save this data in cashout_expense table.

Comment: dd($comments->toArray());.post what you get

Comment: If i write this, it returns me error as "Call to a member function toArray() on string"

Comment: try dd($request->all())

Comment: Obviously `form.cashoutexpenses` is an array on the JS side ("[object Object]" is suggesting JS translating array to string) but your library is not handling it properly, try encoding it somehow. Also why all the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))`? This is doing just converting to JSON and back, it does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

I do not fully understand your code, but I've noticed some potentially problematic parts:

1. `$request->form_cashoutexpenses` most likely is not an array, that is why you probably getting this error. You can check it putting `dd($comments, gettype($comments));` after declaration of `$comments` and rerunning page
2. Having `return` statement inside `foreach` loop at the first line seems to be silly, because the code below will never be executed.

Comment: Oh yes !! It is not an array , Its converting my array into string. If i checked --- **dd($comments, gettype($comments);** . It gives me output as **"[object Object]"** and then **"string"**. Can you tell me now how should i do it ?

Comment: In comments to your questions you were suggested to use `dd($request->all())`. Please do it and post the result in question so that we can understand what data you are dealing with.

Comment: I have edited the question as you suggested , you can check !!

Comment: You can see that output you've added says that you have no `form_cashoutexpenses` in your request. Most probably `form.cashoutexpenses` is one that you need, but anyway, it is sent to your laravel controller as object, not as array. I think you should adjust your js part that sends the form so that it sends an array.